# Windows batch script to provide user input to Perl script

Tags: windows, perl, input, batch-file

I'm running a Perl script that waits for user input. How can I get a batch file to run the script, and provide the input?

I can't modify the Perl source code to accept command line arguments. Here's an illustration.

```
::fill.bat
perl "lazy.pl"
::Pause for 25 seconds tow wait for program to receive user input
ping -n 25 -w 1000 127.0.0.1 > nul 
@Echo off
::Want this to enter "y" when asked "Update script before using? [y]"
Echo y
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try piping your answer into the execution of your perl script.

```
echo y| perl "lazy.pl"
```

This method [works elsewhere](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ITCG/thread/b7baef00-e0e3-41b2-8968-87352769c386/).  I bet it'll probably work here too.

---

For more complex scripted interaction, try [expect](http://docs.activestate.com/activetcl/8.5/expect4win/).  `expect` is a TCL-based script interpreter that allows scripted interactions with console apps.  Here's an example [Expect for Windows](http://docs.activestate.com/activetcl/8.5/expect4win/ex_usage.html) script:

```
spawn perl lazy.pl
expect "Update script before using? [y]"
exp_send "y\r"
expect "Another question? [y]"
exp_send "y\r"
```

Comment: This doesn't work for multiple command line arguments. There has to be an easier way!

Comment: Well, you could have autoit watch for prompts and answer them, or you could use jscript or vbscript to SendKeys I suppose.

Comment: @user1022944 - How many questions do you have to answer in your script?  Maybe you could create a text file with a bunch of `y`'s, one per line, one for each question your perl script asks; then `type answers.txt | perl "lazy.pl"`.  I've never tried such a thing, but it's probably worth a shot.

Comment: About 9-10 arguments are required. I'm not sure this approach would work, but I'll give it a shot